# Getting Status of xml

Tags: php, xml

I am working with the amazon API and I need to check the status of the XML. For example:

```
<GetMatchingProductForIdResult status="Success" IdType="UPC" Id="082686068055">
```

or

```
<GetMatchingProductForIdResult status="ClientError" IdType="UPC" Id="082686068055">
```

How would I go about writing a code that checks if the status is not "Success"? The XML looks like this:

```
<GetMatchingProductForIdResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
  <GetMatchingProductForIdResult status="Success" IdType="UPC" Id="082686068055">
    <Products>
      <Product>
        <Identifiers>
          ... 
        </Identifiers>
        <AttributeSets>
        </AttributeSets>
      </Product>
    </Products>
  </GetMatchingProductForIdResult>
```

Error:

```
<GetMatchingProductForIdResult Id="082686035408" IdType="UPC" status="ClientError">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
      <Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code>
      <Message>Invalid UPC identifier 082686035408 for marketplace ATVPDKIKX0DER</Message>
  </Error>
</GetMatchingProductForIdResult>
```

PHP Code to retrieve the content:

```
if(isset($items->Products->Product->AttributeSets->children($namespace['ns2'])->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->Amount)) { 
    $amount = $items->Products->Product->AttributeSets->children($namespace['ns2'])->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->Amount;
}else{
    $amount = '0.00';
}
```

I was able to create this code to get the ID of the product:

```
//$xml is an open XML file.
$items=$xml->GetMatchingProductForIdResult; 
if(isset($items['Id'])){ 
    $id = $items['Id']; 
}else{
    $id = 'No Id Found';
}
```

The first tag stays throughout the whole XML file. The tag closes at the end of the file. I am using SimpleXML to open, and get all of the other data needed from the file, but I always have an error when the tags in `<AttributeSets>` is not valid. I need to find a way to avoid this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it is not because I am looking to retrieve the information from the `GetMatchingProductForIdResult` tag which is the main tag per item.

Comment: Do you have an example of invalid `<AttributeSets>` and the code you are using to retrieve that element? It seems unlikely an Amazon API would return faulty XML.

Comment: Yes. Will update with error.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Error Added.

Comment: Why you're not checking status attribute before parse AttributeSets?

Comment: @felipsmartins That is why I posted my question. I am not sure how to do it. I have tried things like `if((isset[Status]) != 'ClientError'` but, it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, you've done till now the most hard part, checking for status attr is easier part (okay, I did not tested yet). I'll try do answer, please a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, there is many ways to go. But as you want just detect whether a error or success occurr:

```
<?php 

$xmldata = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<GetMatchingProductForIdResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
    <GetMatchingProductForIdResult status="Success" IdType="UPC" Id="082686068055">
        ....
    </GetMatchingProductForIdResult>
</GetMatchingProductForIdResponse>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($xmldata);
$items = $xml->GetMatchingProductForIdResult;
$ERROR_FOUND = 'Error' == $items->attributes()->status;

if ($ERROR_FOUND) {
    // do something on error, such as return or exit()...
} 
// continue xml data parsing
```

Comment: Wait. Since the response will be with many other responses, I could just implement the last 4 lines?

Comment: You mean, a loop I guess, right? Where there migth be many GetMatchingProductForIdResponse, is that?

Comment: Yes, I have the loop already implemented, but could I just put this at the beginning of the loop?

Comment: @Robert Of course yes! You can write a while loop somewhat like this: `while ($ERROR_NOT_FOUND) {//code}` or somthing like `while () { if ($not_error) //... }`. That is the point! The implementation is up to you!

Comment: Do you have any social media so I can contact you if I have any other questions?

Comment: @Robert sure! My facebook id is https://www.facebook.com/felipemartinskazumi, my gmail is felipsmartins at gmail dot com